# MySQL query row based on current row

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

[image: Table of Categories]

Above is my table. Now what I want to achieve is query where type is "main" including all "sub" where parent is equal to the id of the current row. How can I achieve that? Any help would be much appreciated!

Below is my current code:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name",$user,$pass) or die("DB Connection failed!!");
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_categories WHERE type="main"');
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
//first loop i should get Electronics, Laptops, Mobile Phones
//second loop i should get Fashion, Men, Women
}
```

I don't wanna perform another query inside the while loop.

Comment: In sql ('normal' sql, i.e. not cursor etc) is set-based. As such, there is no 'current row'. Explain what you need, and what you tried.

Comment: Who is current row? Are you referring to the rows where type is "main"? Show us the output you're expecting

Comment: OP updated.. @AlexandruSeverin

Comment: OP updated @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but this is how you can do it at DB level.

```
select * from tbl_categories 
where parent in
(
    select id from tbl_categories
    where type='main'
)
```

If you just want to get details for `Fashion`, then use this

```
select * from tbl_categories 
where parent in
(
    select id from tbl_categories
    where type='main'
    and Category='Fashion'
)
```

**SQL Fiddle example**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea58e/2

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your data: Why is the `parent` of `fashion = 1`? I would think it was `null`, same as `Electronics`. Considering that, try this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT, category VARCHAR(255), Type VARCHAR(50), Parent int)
;

INSERT @T
        ( id, category, Type, Parent )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Electronics', 'Main', NULL)
,       ( 2, 'Laptops', 'Sub', 1)
,       ( 3, 'Mobile phones', 'Sub', 1)
,       ( 4, 'Fashion', 'Main', NULL)
,       ( 5, 'Men', 'Sub', 4)
,       ( 6, 'Women', 'Sub', 4)

SELECT      T2.*
FROM        @T AS T
INNER JOIN  @T AS T2
        ON  T2.Parent = T.id
WHERE       T.Type = 'Main'
```

Result:

```
id  category    Type    Parent
2   Laptops Sub 1
3   Mobile phones   Sub 1
5   Men Sub 4
6   Women   Sub 4
```